# Extract substring from strings (in a particular format) from a file using bash or sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have an input file, an example of which is shown below : 
`(?U0 ?U2 ?U9 ?U11 ?U21)` 
 I want to extract all the numbers after `?U` to an output file as: 
`0 2 9 11 21`
 Please help me in this regard, I am new to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use grep but it produces output in each per line.

```
grep -oP '\?U\K\d+' file
```

or

```
$ echo '(?U0 ?U2 ?U9 ?U11 ?U21)' | grep -oP '\?U\K\d+' | paste -s -d " " -
0 2 9 11 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed you can do:

```
s='(?U0 ?U2 ?U9 ?U11 ?U21)'
sed 's/?U\([0-9]\+\)/\1/g; s/[()]//g' <<< "$s"
0 2 9 11 21
```

Answer (score 0):

simple sed

```
echo "(?U0 ?U2 ?U9 ?U11 ?U21)" | sed 's/[()?U]//g'
```

output
0 2 9 11 21

deleting all unneeded characters, you can put in set [...] if needed another characters

or more universal

```
echo "(?U0 ?U2 ?U9 ?U11 ?U21)" | sed 's/[^0-9 ]*//g'
```

deleting all non-digit characters (and not space)

Answer (score 0):

With grep:

```
out="$(grep -oP '(?<=\?U)\d+' filepath |tr -s '\n' ' ')"
out="${out% }"
echo "$out" >outfilepath
```